# How to position your hands during Netilas Yadayim

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing

I heard that the Mishna Brurah says that when you wash Netilas Yadayim, you should hold you hands palm up, but when I do this, the other side of my hand doesn't get wet.

So how do you position your hands when you wash Netilas Yadayim?

Comment: Is this a halacha question or a best practice question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `I heard that the Mishna Brurah says that when you wash Netilas Yadayim, you should hold you hands palm up`

**-->** Yes the source is in Gemara Sota (quoted below)

> `but when I do this, the other side of my hand doesn't get wet.`

**-->** The fingers only must be wet according to Shulchan Aruch.  Additionally if you pour one reviit in one timr,  no need to position upward the hands as @DoubleAA indicated in comments.  And as the RMA stated in name of the Agur in name of Or Zarua and Hagahot Ashre,  3 X ,  even less than reviit eachvtime,  remedies the problem.  If you can not make both sises of the hand wet i  upward positioning,  this both solutions are good enough lechatechilla.

**SA OC 162, 1:**

> הנוטל צריך להגביה ידיו (דהיינו ראשי אצבעותיו) למעלה שלא יצאו מים חוץ לפרק ויחזרו ויטמאו את הידים. ‏
>
> ‏**הגה:** והוא הדין אם משפילן מתחלת הנטילה עד סופה דשפיר דמי רק שיזהר שלא  יגביה תחלה ראשי אצבעותיו ואחר כך ישפילם דאז יצאו המים חוץ לפרק ויחזרו ויטמאו הידים (בית יוסף בשם מהר"י בן חביב). ‏
>   והיינו כשאינו נוטל כל היד עד מקום חבור היד עם הזרוע אבל אם נוטל עד שם אין צריך להגביה ידיו. (ויש חולקים בזה). וכן אם שפך על שתי ידיו רביעית בפעם אחת כיון דאין שם מים טמאים כלל אין צריך להגביה ידיו וכן המטביל ידיו אין צריך להגביה ידיו. {דעת הרא"ש לפי מגן אברהם}‏
>
> (יש אומרים דאם שופך על ידיו ג' פעמים אין צריך ליזהר בכל זה וכן נהגו להקל) (אגור בשם אור זרוע והגהות אשירי פרק כ"ה).‏

1. **Fingers upward** to avoid the round trip of water from the area up to the metacarpophalangeal joint to fingers. **but bediavad, if he doesn't make this, mishna Berura**
2. **Or downward from the starting of netila up to the drying** (this is a Machloket, see the adverse opinion in paragraph 3)
3. The previous conditions are needed only if the netila did not wash the whole hand up to the elbow {and some opinion think up to the armpit}, but if it did wash up to the elbow, the water round trip should not make unclean the hand/s.
4. As mentioned, condition 3 is not unanimously established, and even in the case of washing up to the window, the hands need to be upward.
5. If both hands were washed at once,  there is no unclean water and the above conditions are not necessary.
6. Some poskim said that if each hand was washed threefold the above conditions are not necessary;  such is the minhag (Agur), the Mishna Berura in name of Chaye Adam has doubts on this solution.
7. Magen Avraham (and **Mishna Berura sk 16** ) added that ***if each water jet is reviit,  there is no unclean water and consequently the above conditions concerning upward position of fingers and hand are not relevant*** and this solution is surely better than 3 X netilat of less than reviit (1 x reviit is better than 3 X (1/3 reviit)) .

   > ובמטביל ידיו או נוטל מרביעית אין שם מים טמאים כלל וא"צ להגביה, ‏

---

### sources in Chazal

---

There are discussions if there above rule concerning the wrist concerns really the writing or the metacarpo phalanx  joints. If netila up to the elbow eliminates all problems. To make sense for this halachot a knowledge in the netila nature is needed.

Gemara Sota 4b:

> ... ‏אמר רב מים ראשונים צריך שיגביה ידיו למעלה
>
> R'Hiyya B'Ashi said in the name of Rab: With the first washing [before the meal] it is necessary to lift the hands up;
>
> תניא נמי הכי הנוטל ידיו צריך שיגביה ידיו למעלה שמא יצאו המים חוץ לפרק ויחזרו ויטמאו את הידים ‏
>
> There is a similar teaching: Who washes his hands [before the meal] must lift them up lest the water pass beyond the joint, flow back and render them unclean.

Rashi:

> כדתנן במסכת ידים (פ''ב מ''ג) שצריך ליתן המים על ידיו שני פעמים הראשונים מטהרין את הידים והשניים מטהרין את המים הטופחים על ידיו שנטמאו בתחילה מחמת ידים
>
> As taugth in Mishna in Masechet Yadayim, one must pour water twice, the first water clean the hand, the second water clean the first water which beads on hands, this first water became unclean at the beginning, because of the hands.
>
> ותנן התם הידים מטמאות ומטהרות עד הפרק
>
> And they taught in Mishna that the cleanness issue of the hands concerns the part which is below the joint.
>
> כלומר מן הפרק ולמטה גזרו עליהן להיות שניות ופוסלות את התרומה ומטהרות בנטילה עד הפרק שעד הפרק צריך נטילה
>
> that is, from the joint downward, the wise decreed that the hands are unclean (second degree of uncleanness which make unclean foods and drinks, not man and tools), they make truma unsuitable; they become clean by washing up to the join. Netila must be upward up to the joint. {see below a Gemara<sup>(1)</sup> regarding which joint is it}

נטל את הראשונים ואת השניים עד הפרק וחזרו ליד טהורים שהרי טיהרו השניים את הראשונים נטל את הראשונים חוץ לפרק ואת השניים עד הפרק וחזרו ליד טמאה כלומר יצאו הראשונים חוץ לפרק ועל השניים לא הקפיד ליטול עד מקום שיצאו הראשונים אלא עד הפרק כמשפט וחחזרו הראשונים ליד טמאה שהרי נטמאו תחילה מחמת הידים והשניים לא טיהרו את היוצאים

> If the second water did not reach all the areas covered by the first water, first water will runoff from the top of the joint and make the hand unclean.

הילכך צריך שיגביה ראשי אצבעותיו למעלה שמא יצאו מים הראשונים ויחזרו ויטמאו את הידים: ‏

> thus one must position upward the fingers so that is no water that come back on the hands.

This i the Rashi parshanut but the study of the halacha imply to know others opinions. I reported Rashi as a example.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Gemara Chulin 106ab

> Our Rabbis taught: The washing of the hands for common food [must reach] up to the joint ( **proximal interphalangeal** , Rashi): for terumah [it must reach] up to the joint ( **metacarpophalangeal** , Rashi); the sanctification of the hands and feet for Temple service [must reach] up to the joint ( **elbow** , Rashi  ) ...  Rab said: Up to here (as explained above, Rashi) is [the washing] for common food; up to here for terumah. Samuel said: Up to here both for common food and for terumah, adopting the stricter view.(  **metacarpophalangeal**  ) Rab Shesheth said, up to here both for common food and for terumah, adopting the lenient view.( **proximal interphalangeal** ) Bar Hadaya said: I was once standing before R'Ammi and he said: Up to here both for common food and for terumah, adopting the stricter view ( **metacarpophalangeal**  ). And you must not suppose that R'Ammi [said so] because he was a priest, (the truma criterion) for R'Meyasha, the grandson of R'Joshua B'Levi, who was a Levite also said: Up to here both for common food and for terumah, adopting the stricter view.

See the Tosfot, and you will understand that there are several translation of the joints. We explained according to Rashi only. In Shulchan Aruch,

Comment: added the mishna berura reference as asked in the OP